# PHP: imap_body -> get only the message-text

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm using php imap-functions to fetch mail-contents from my mailserver.

This works great so far with headers - but I would like to fetch the "pure" Text the message contains.

At the moment it looks like this:

Body:

```
--Apple-Mail=_0DCDC337-EC65-4217-B5CB-B3A2675D8573
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=utf-8

This is the text i want

--Apple-Mail=_0DCDC337-EC65-4217-B5CB-B3A2675D8573
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset=utf-8

Quoted text

--Apple-Mail=_0DCDC337-EC65-4217-B5CB-B3A2675D8573--
```

This is the result if I use:

```
$body       =       imap_body($connection, $moverview->msgno,2);
```

The best case would be if I only get the latest text ("This is the text i want") - not even the quotations.

Any idea how I could solve this?

Thanks in advance :-)